# pub get error: Cannot create link...(OS Error: Incorrect function)

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I have an error while trying to get the packages for the angular dart codelab:

```
--- 10:01:28 Running pub get ... ---
Pub get failed, [1] Resolving dependencies........................................
Cannot create link, path = 'X:\Dev\Dart\ng-darrrt-codelab-master\packages\angular' (OS Error: Incorrect function.
, errno = 1)
```

I tried to remove everything in the packages folder and try again.
All the packages download correctly, but the "***Cannot create link***" error persists...

I'm on windows server 2008 and I use DartEditor 1.2.0

Comment: Maybe the problem is the network drive. Can you try it on a local drive?

Comment: Indeed. I moved the folder on a local drive and get-pub is now running well. Thx!

Comment: This is a known problem with Windows + symbolic links + networks drive.

Comment: Problem in that the most operations of the pub package manager based on the creation and usage of symbolic links. You should always take this into account as the possible limitation or even as the potential problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of downloading packages for each project, `pub` downloads them to a cache directory and symbolic links it to your `packages` directory. This saves bandwidth because instead of downloading the package every time all it needs to do is symbolic link it from the cache. If `pub` is unable to create a symbolic link it throws the `Cannot create link` error. On windows it is not possible to symbolically link a folder from a local drive to a network drive. You can circumvent error by moving the file to a local drive and then running `pub get`.

Comment: You are not quite correct. It saves bandwidth not because create symbolic links to the local cache. It saves bandwidth because it put downloaded packages into cache. But if the package manager will not make symbolic links to cache but will still copy these previously downloaded packages into application folder (from local cache) then this also saves bandwidth. Many other package managers does not create symbolic links but they also saves bandwidth (uses cache) and have not problems as the Dart package manager.

Comment: @mezoni feel free to edit it because I don't exactly understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: How to move the file to a local drive and then run pub get?

Comment: @0xcaff Thanks i am using windows on mac using VM, i was creating flutter app in mac drive and used it on network so now i put project in `C:` windows drive and `flutter clean .` it just clean `cache` and build windows app now its working.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the project folder to the drive where Flutter is installed. For example, if your Flutter engine lies in `C:` drive then move your Project folder to `C:`

Then, run `start ms-settings:developers` in command prompt and activate Developers mode.

After that, run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` commands and you will be good to go.