# Set min/max screen size in Flutter windows

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

I am developing a Windows flutter application. The app has already mobile versions and I am converting to windows. The mobile design is already there but I need to convert it to windows and the problem is the design is not ready yet.

For this reason, I have been given a task to find out how to give maximum width and height for the application so that the user cannot change the app screen size using the mouse.

Is there a way to implement this on Flutter windows?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, this can be done and it also avoids the problem mentioned by [@Khamidjon Khamidov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11984583/khamidjon-khamidov). To achieve this, you will need to make changes in 3 files:

1. pubspec.yaml
2. main.cpp (at windows\runner\main.cpp)
3. main.dart

**Add the code below to your pubspec.yaml, under dependencies and save the file.**

```
window_size:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding
      path: plugins/window_size
```

**Change the code below in main.cpp:**

```
Win32Window::Size size(1280, 720);
to
Win32Window::Size size(min_width, min_height)
```

The above code will ensure your app startup at the preferred size. Replace min_width and min_height with either your minimum or maximum value pair.

**Modify your main.dart as show below:**

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  if (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux || Platform.isMacOS) {
    setWindowTitle('My App');
    setWindowMaxSize(const Size(max_width, max_height));
    setWindowMinSize(const Size(min_width, min_height));
  }

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Replace max_width, max_height, min_width and min_height with your preferred value.

Note:
If you want a non-sizable form use the same min and max values.

Comment: Update:
since March 15, 2022 git://  protocol on port 9418 is no longer supported.
you can use https:// protocol to https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding.git

Answer (score 8):

You can use this [Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager) to add the ability to control your window instance.

**Installation**

add this your your `pubspec.yaml` :

```
dependencies:
  window_manager: ^0.2.7
```

**Usage**

in your `main()` method add this :

```dart
import 'dart:io'; 
import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';

void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await windowManager.ensureInitialized();
  if (Platform.isWindows) {
    WindowManager.instance.setMinimumSize(const Size(1200, 600));
    WindowManager.instance.setMaximumSize(const Size(1200, 600));
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

and replace 1200, and 600 with your preferred size.

Comment: Imported packages are: `import 'dart:io';` and `import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';`

Answer (score 5):

`METHOD 1`

As @Stefano mentioned, I could use this library:

```
dependencies:
  window_size:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding.git
      path: plugins/window_size
```

.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:window_size/window_size.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (Platform.isWindows) {
    setWindowMaxSize(const Size(1024, 768));
    setWindowMinSize(const Size(512, 384));
    Future<Null>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        setWindowFrame(Rect.fromCenter(center: Offset(1000, 500), width: 600, height: 1000));
    });
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

But the problem here is that the window size is being set to default so it is changing its size after few seconds.

`METHOD 2`

Because, the first method didn't work as I expected I mixed the both methods:

In **main.dart**:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (Platform.isWindows) {
    setWindowMaxSize(const Size(1024, 768));
    setWindowMinSize(const Size(512, 384));
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

In **lib/windows/runner/win32_window.cpp**:
// this method already exists inside the file
bool Win32Window::CreateAndShow(const std::wstring& title,
const Point& origin,
const Size& size) {
Destroy();

```
  const wchar_t* window_class =
      WindowClassRegistrar::GetInstance()->GetWindowClass();

  const POINT target_point = {static_cast<LONG>(/*x // change here to move to center*/ 550),  // before -> origin.x
                              static_cast<LONG>(/*y // change here to move vertically*/ origin.y)}; // before -> origin.y
  HMONITOR monitor = MonitorFromPoint(target_point, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
  UINT dpi = FlutterDesktopGetDpiForMonitor(monitor);
  double scale_factor = dpi / 96.0;

  HWND window = CreateWindow(
      window_class, title.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
      Scale(/* x // move to center */ 550, scale_factor), Scale(/* y // move screen vertically */ origin.y, scale_factor),// before -> origin.x, origin.y
      Scale(/* width  // set default width */ 450, scale_factor), Scale(/* height // set default height */ 800, scale_factor), // before -> size.width, size.height
      nullptr, nullptr, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), this);

  if (!window) {
    return false;
  }

  return OnCreate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can limit the size of a Windows Flutter app by using the `window_size` package.

To use it in our app, we need to add it in our `pubspec.yaml` dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  window_size:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding.git
      path: plugins/window_size
```

And use it at initialization as follows below:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:window_size/window_size.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (Platform.isWindows) {
    setWindowMaxSize(const Size(1024, 768));
    setWindowMinSize(const Size(512, 384));
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: But, initially the screen is becoming larger(not becoming what I set as min/max). It is changing only after I try to resize

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]
The above Solution is Outdated and throws an error.

According to the official documentation by Flutter team, the [Supporting Windows UI guidelines](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/windows/building#supporting-windows-ui-guidelines) section provides the latest solution.

According to this, use the [bitsdojo_window](https://pub.dev/packages/bitsdojo_window) plugin from pub.dev to Set window size, minimum size and maximum size, position and etc.

You will face 1 or 2 errors while installing this plugin. To solve that problem please check this issue for complete [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555634/pub-get-error-cannot-create-link-os-error-incorrect-function/76841526#76841526).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out [bitsdojo_window](https://github.com/bitsdojo/bitsdojo_window)

It require you some platform specific changes but then you can customize the  window title bar from dart code

```dart
+   doWhenWindowReady(() {
+     const initialSize = Size(600, 450);
+     appWindow.minSize = initialSize;
+     appWindow.size = initialSize;
+     appWindow.alignment = Alignment.center;
+     appWindow.show();
+   });
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use methods like this, without additional packages. This is an example of setting the minimum window size:

await MethodChannel('desktop_window').invokeMethod('setMinWindowSize', {'width': 500, 'height': 800});

Comment: The answer needs more detail as to where to call this - for example, adding it before `runApp` in the `main` method throws an exception