# Bottom overflow by pixels

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a login screen inside my flutter app. But for some reason i'm getting an warning (bottom overflowed by 30 pixels) and i don't know why this is happening.

I tried:

- Wrapping my widgets to a **SingleChildScrollView**
- Using **resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false**

But none of these solutions worked.

**My Login Screen:**

```
import 'package:PrivMessage/Screens/reset_password.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';


class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {

  String email = "";
  String password = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF263238),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Image.asset("assets/images/back_icon.png", height: 30, width: 30,),
                      iconSize: 40,
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Go to previews screen
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),

                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, top: 12),
                    child: const Text("Sign in", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white, fontSize: 23),),
                  ),
                  const Spacer()
                ],
              ),

              const SizedBox(height: 30),

              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                child: const Text("Sign in to continue",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 35),
                ),
              ),

              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                child: const Text("Sign in to your account below to\ncontinue and start chatting with safety.",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 17),
                ),
              ),

              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: const Color(0xFFECECEC)
                ),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  onChanged: (newText) {
                    setState(() {

                    });
                  },
                  cursorColor: Colors.black,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
                      hintText: "Email address"),
                ),
              ),

              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: const Color(0xFFECECEC)
                ),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  onChanged: (newText) {
                    setState(() {

                    });
                  },
                  cursorColor: Colors.black,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
                      hintText: "Password"),
                ),
              ),

              Row(
                children: [
                  const Spacer(),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 40),
                    child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft, child: const ResetPasswordScreen()));
                        },
                        child: const Text("Forgot password?")
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),

              SizedBox(
                width: 1000,
                height: 50,
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ), primary: Colors.indigo),
                    child: const Text("Sign in", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              const Spacer(),
              const Spacer(),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              const Text("Made by George Sepetadelis", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 18)),
              const SizedBox(height: 20)

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try out this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  String email = "";
  String password = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF263238),
        body: Center(
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Image.asset(
                        "assets/images/back_icon.png",
                        height: 30,
                        width: 30,
                      ),
                      iconSize: 40,
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Go to previews screen
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, top: 12),
                    child: const Text(
                      "Sign in",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 23),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Spacer()
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                child: const Text(
                  "Sign in to continue",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 35),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                child: const Text(
                  "Sign in to your account below to\ncontinue and start chatting with safety.",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 17),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: const Color(0xFFECECEC)),
                margin:
                    const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  onChanged: (newText) {
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  cursorColor: Colors.black,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 15, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
                      hintText: "Email address"),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: const Color(0xFFECECEC)),
                margin:
                    const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  onChanged: (newText) {
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  cursorColor: Colors.black,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 15, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
                      hintText: "Password"),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  const Spacer(),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 40),
                    child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          // Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft, child: const ResetPasswordScreen()));
                        },
                        child: const Text("Forgot password?")),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 1000,
                height: 50,
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        primary: Colors.indigo),
                    child:
                        const Text("Sign in", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              const Spacer(),
              const Spacer(),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              const SizedBox(height: 20)
            ],
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 16, 8, 16),
          child: Text(
            "Made by George Sepetadelis",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 18),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but the "made by " text is not at the bottom of the page

Comment: @GSepetadelis, I have edited my answer. Check it now, it will contain  "made by " text is not at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Try swipe `SafeArea` with `Scaffold` , and Use `SingleChildScrollView` above main `Column`.

Comment: I tried and is not working :(

Comment: @GoldenLion i tried it and it stills not works

Comment: your getting an overflow error when the window is resized small. sizedbox or constrainedBox did not prevent the overflow

Answer (score 2):

Add a container of height 600 and wrap it with a SingleChildScrollView and add scrollbars if desired

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body:SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(height:600,child:
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Image.asset("assets/images/back_icon.png", height: 30, width: 30,),
                      iconSize: 40,
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Go to previews screen
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),

                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, top: 12),
                    child: const Text("Sign in", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white, fontSize: 23),),
                  ),
                  const Spacer()
                ],
              ),

              const SizedBox(height: 30),

              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                child: const Text("Sign in to continue",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 35),
                ),
              ),

              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                child: const Text("Sign in to your account below to\ncontinue and start chatting with safety.",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 17),
                ),
              ),

              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: const Color(0xFFECECEC)
                ),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  onChanged: (newText) {
                    setState(() {

                    });
                  },
                  cursorColor: Colors.black,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
                      hintText: "Email address"),
                ),
              ),

              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: const Color(0xFFECECEC)
                ),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  onChanged: (newText) {
                    setState(() {

                    });
                  },
                  cursorColor: Colors.black,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
                      hintText: "Password"),
                ),
              ),

              Row(
                children: [
                  const Spacer(),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 40),
                    child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          
                        },
                        child: const Text("Forgot password?")
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),

              SizedBox(
                width: 1000,
                height: 50,
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ), primary: Colors.indigo),
                    child: const Text("Sign in", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              const Spacer(),
              const Spacer(),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              const Text("Made by xxx", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 18)),
              const SizedBox(height: 20)
          ],
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    )));
  }
}
```

Comment: if you don't want scrolling then here is how to set a fixed sized window in flutter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69755091/set-min-max-screen-size-in-flutter-windows or you can use a dialog widget