# Disabled Window resize in Flutter Desktop

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building an app with Flutter(For desktop users) and it's kind of hard to make the app responsive for every screen size because of big forms and table that shouldn't be used on small screens (less than 13').

Is there any way to prevent users from resizing the windows ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set min/max screen size in Flutter windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69755091/set-min-max-screen-size-in-flutter-windows)

Answer (score 1):

by using package called **desktop_window**
[pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_window)

then inside main , use these 3 lines and it will work ✔ :

```
void main() async {
Size size = await DesktopWindow.getWindowSize();
// setting min and max with the same size to prevent resizing
await DesktopWindow.setMinWindowSize(Size(1920,1080));
await DesktopWindow.setMaxWindowSize(Size(1920,1080));
}
```