# Is there any way in Flutter to set the minimum window size for Windows?

Tags: flutter, windows, dart, flutter-windows, window-size

Many Windows programs allow you to reduce the window size up to a certain size. However, when I create a new project in Flutter, the window can be shrunk without any restrictions, so that nothing of the content is visible anymore. Is there any way to set this minimum size?

Until now I have done some unsuccessful research on the internet. The only thing I have managed to do is to read the current window size and then display a message if the window is too small instead of the actual window content. This is better than nothing, but still not what I want to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69755091/set-min-max-screen-size-in-flutter-windows

Answer (score 1):

A `Container()` widget has a parameter called `constraints`. With that you can set minimum and maximum sizes.

```
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxHeight: screenHeight,
        maxWidth:  screenWidth,
        minHeight: screenHeight * 0.5,
        minWidth: screenWidth * 0.5,
        ),
    );
```

You may also use a `ConstrainedBox()` widget instead of a `Container()`.

```
ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      maxHeight: screenHeight,
      maxWidth:  screenWidth,
      minHeight: screenHeight * 0.5,
      minWidth: screenWidth * 0.5,
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. I tried both variants, but unfortunately the window can still be reduced indefinitely. When the window gets too small, it just gives an error. Is there maybe something else I can try?

Comment: Sorry that it didn't work for you. May you please try the solution on this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69755091/set-min-max-screen-size-in-flutter-windows