How to avoid SliverAppBar's elements to go above the BackButton?
I have a SliverAppBar with some elements inside, check the 3 images where I resize the app window smaller and smaller.
1
2
3
I would like to avoid the texts and icons from going above the BackButton, is there a way to do that?
Here there is a piece of my simple code:
CustomScrollView(
        primary: true,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          const SliverAppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            pinned: true,
            title: Text(
              'Home',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            leading: BackButton(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Text(
                  'text1',
                  maxLines: 1,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.tsunami,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Text(
                  'text2',
                  maxLines: 1,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
            ],
          ),
),

Thanks in advance!
*Note: my code doesn't produce errors and I understand that probably it will never happen in a device where the text and icons are above the BackButton but still I would like to know if there is a way to avoid it.

Seems pointless to try and fix this as a device would never be that small?

@DevonRay is true, but if you really want to avoid it then use MediaQuery. set a minimum width constraint, if width is less then minimum, you can remove actions. Like how navbar is handled in websites

You can restrict the window size of your app specially if it runs on windows or macOS:
You can use packages like window_manager and set the minimum with of the screen
dependencies:
  window_manager: ^0.3.8

 void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (Platform.isWindows) {
    setWindowMinSize(const Size(512, 384));
    Future<Null>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        setWindowFrame(Rect.fromCenter(center: Offset(1000, 500), width: 600, height: 1000));
    });
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}

That will never let the user minimize the app screen less than 512px, and your app bar never get shrinked.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70048363/24076237 I combined this answer with yours to get a good final result, thanks for the idea.
